# Ruby on Rails: setting up a model that belongs to two parents (one of which can also be a grandparent)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up a Rails 4 with 3 models, but I'm not sure how to make this work.

Brand:

```
has_many    :collections
has_many    :items
```

Collection:

```
belongs_to  :brand
has_many    :items
```

Item:

```
belongs_to  :collection
belongs_to  :brand
```

An item must belong to a brand.

An item can only belong to a collection that is also from the same brand.

How can I set up my models and database to make this work?

I thought about doing a polymorphic association for this, but doesn't that kill the relationship between collection and brand? Or could this be accomplished through join tables somehow?

Here is my horrendous drawing of the relationship:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, I think it's best to use a [Polymorphic Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Maybe like this:

```
# app/models/brand.rb
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections
  has_many :items, as: :itemparent
end

# app/models/collection.rb
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :items, as: :itemparent
end

# app/models/collection.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itemparent, polymorphic: true
end
```

The items table migration would look like:

```
class CreateItmes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.integer :itemparent_id
      t.string  :itemparent_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This way, you preserve the clear association between `Brand` and `Collection`, while give `Item` the ability to have any kind of parent.

Comment: Ah, see, here's where the tricky part comes in. An item can also belong to a brand without belonging to any collection. Not sure how this would work... In the case that it does belong to a collection, the collection must also belong to the same brand.

Comment: @Michelle I've edited my answer, does it comply now?

Comment: Thanks so much! So through a polymorphic association, if I were to call something like @brand.collection.items - would that give me the same results as @collection.items?

Comment: You would be able to call `@brand.collections[i].items` which would give you the same as `@collection.items`. Since `@brand.collections` returns an array of `Collection`s whose brand is `@brand`, you should choose one of them with the index like `[i]` or with any other array filtering method, and then get that single collection's items with `.items`.